# to skip lines at the end of a text (i.e. not binary) data file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a data file with 15 header lines. I can plot data adding `skip 15` (otherwise gnuplot writes those lines and warning messages in the dialog box). But I've got some text lines at the end of the data file, too, which are always displayed in the dialog box along with warning messages. In order to avoid that... is there a way to `skip` the last n lines at the end of a text (i.e. not binary) data file?

Comment: Please provide some example data. What is your code? What are your warning messages? What is your gnuplot version? For example with gnuplot 5.2.8 I don't get warning messages when having text lines. gnuplot just ignores these lines for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `every` keyword, which is more flexible. However, you cannot directly skip the last n lines. You can count the number of entries with shell scripts or using gnuplot's `stats`, and pass it to `every`. On Gnuplot 5, I don't get warnings if the last lines are text, though.

The file `data.txt`:

```
some text
as header
1
2
3
no more data
in this file
```

can be plotted with

```
plot "data.txt" every::2
```

Comment: just to mention a "little hidden" detail: `stats 'data.txt'` will tell you via the gnuplot variable `STATS_records` the number of lines with numeric entries (in your example `3`) . But you can use `stats 'data.txt' u 0` and you will get `7`.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has the standard linux utility `head`, you can pipe the data file through a head command to remove the last N lines.

```
plot '< head --lines=-15 datafile.txt'
```